# Any work-around for the performance regression related to external monitors/HDMI?

Tags: graphic-drivers, kernel, hdmi

I know that this is an issue with the linux kernel, but I'm hoping that there is a work-around. I use my laptop as a home-theater machine, connectting it to my TV with HDMI.  Unfortunately, since the upgrade to the 4.4 kernel, there has been a tremendous performance regression and there are artifacts appearing on my television.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps you. I know it's another distro, but their documentarion is awesome and can help you in many other situations.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#SNA_issues